# How to read a variable width white space string table into a panda dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I am a newbie to pandas and trying to read a complex string into a dataframe. The problem I am having is the data gets read in character by character. What do I have to do to get this data read in so the dataframe captures the rows and columns? Much appreciated!

Here is what one line looks like:

1  85  58  72   6   0   7 0.00  0.0    0  6.7 15 230   M    M   3        19 240

[image]

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
    import urllib2
    import math 
    import json
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import Timestamp
    import os, sys
    import re
    import numpy as np
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import csv

    sites = {'dlh':'1'}

    prdurl = 'https://api.weather.gov/products/types/cf6/locations/' 
    cf6url = 'https://api.weather.gov/products/'

    current_date = datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)
    current_day = current_date.strftime('%d') 

    def make_request(url,params):
        req = urllib2.Request(url+params)
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            return json.loads(response.read())
        except urllib2.HTTPError as error:
            if error.code == 400: print error.msg

    def main():

        for id in sites:
            apijson = make_request(prdurl,id)
            for key in apijson:
                if key != '@context':
                    webjson  = apijson['@graph']
                    for x in webjson:
                        valid = x['issuanceTime']
                        date_obj = datetime.strptime(valid,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00')
                        day = date_obj.strftime('%d')
                        if current_day == day:
                            newparam = x['id']
        cf6json = make_request(cf6url,newparam)
        for y in cf6json:
            if y == 'productText':

                cf6data = cf6json['productText']
                for line in cf6data.splitlines():
                if line.startswith('==='):
                    count = count + 1 
                if count == 2:
                    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(line)
                    print df
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 1: Get the data:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.weather.gov/products/16a535da-eb2c-4580-9725-b536890e923d')
data = response.json()['productText']
```

### Step 2: Clean and reshape the data:

#### Split it into a `list` and remove `''`:

```
data_list = data.split('\n')
data_clean = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', data_list))
```

#### Write the relevant data to a csv:

```
from pathlib import Path

f = Path.cwd() / 'weather.csv'

with f.open(mode='w') as wf:
    count = 0
    for line in data_clean:
        if line.startswith('==='):
            count += 1
        if (count == 2 and not line.startswith('===')) or (line.startswith('DY MAX')):
            wf.write(f'{line}\n')
```

### Step 3: Create the `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('weather.csv', sep='\\s+')
```

#### Final:

[image]

- It's always about getting the data into the correct form

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would vote up, but I do not have the reputation points to do so yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this code

if you have data.txt like this :

```
col1 col2
===================
aa bb
===================
jjjjjjj kkkkkkkk
```

Then, you can use skiprows to skip some rows, and separator is the space ( sep=" ")

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=" ", header=None,skiprows=[1,3])
data.columns = ["col1","col2"]
data
```

Result :

```
    col1    col2
0   col1    col2
1   aa  bb
2   jjjjjjj kkkkkkkk
```

Regarding the very specific code that you added. If you want to read lines one by one, then for each one you can decide what to ignore and when. Also, using split and expand=True. "When using expand=True, the split elements will expand out into separate columns" 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

```
    cf6data = cf6json['productText']  
    start = False         
    for line in cf6data.splitlines():

        if start or "DY MAX" in line: 
            start = True
            s = pd.Series(line)
            line = s.str.split(expand=True)
            Results = Results.append(line,ignore_index=True)
            print(Results)
```

Play with this code a little bit, clean some lines and it should work! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would vote up, but I do not have the reputation points to do so yet.